# Merge a column based on 2nd column

Tags: awk, gawk

I have file looking like this:

```
pw1jc5ssyt6hx618,254343
ysezaratlycpuggl,254333
pht92h4adr3mrbz3,254343
hguvgstqxu3gowfg,254344
gqjp2rsjmk1a2v9c,254333
twdzyi2ddbnrfknd,254333
gcmj7krrx5x6nf8r,254341
tpqorqbyrg1nmm7s,254333
alnac47rt8d4ege3,254343
```

I want to merge this file based on 2nd column, with `-` as a delimiter, so that the result looks like this:

```
254343,pw1jc5ssyt6hx618-pht92h4adr3mrbz3-alnac47rt8d4ege3
254333,ysezaratlycpuggl-gqjp2rsjmk1a2v9c-twdzyi2ddbnrfknd-tpqorqbyrg1nmm7s
254344,hguvgstqxu3gowfg
254341,gcmj7krrx5x6nf8r
```

Comment: Please format the text.

Comment: is blank lines are part of your file ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`awk` is your friend

```
$ cat 299360
ipw1jc5ssyt6hx618,254343
ysezaratlycpuggl,254333
pht92h4adr3mrbz3,254343
hguvgstqxu3gowfg,254344
gqjp2rsjmk1a2v9c,254333
twdzyi2ddbnrfknd,254333
gcmj7krrx5x6nf8r,254341
tpqorqbyrg1nmm7s,254333
alnac47rt8d4ege3,254343
$ awk -v FS="," '/^$/{next} # for empty line go to next record
                {if(NR==1){ # checking for first record
                f2[$2]=$1;next} # Adding $1 to array f2 at index $2
                else{
                if($2 in f2){ # Check if $2 is already an index in f2
                f2[$2]=f2[$2]"-"$1;next #appending "-$1" to current value
                }
                else{
                f2[$2]=$1;next
                }
                }}
                END{ # This line will be processed at the end
                for(i in f2){  # for all the indexes i in f2
                printf "%s,%s\n",i,f2[i] #printing in the desired format
                }
                }
                ' 299360
254341,gcmj7krrx5x6nf8r
254333,ysezaratlycpuggl-gqjp2rsjmk1a2v9c-twdzyi2ddbnrfknd-tpqorqbyrg1nmm7s
254343,pw1jc5ssyt6hx618-pht92h4adr3mrbz3-alnac47rt8d4ege3
254344,hguvgstqxu3gowfg
```

**Explanation**

1. `FS=","` – FS is awk's built-in variable that stands for field separator. Setting field separator to `,` will set `,` as the delimiter.
2. You access fields by `$1`, `$2` and so on.
3. The awk script is enclosed in single quotes;
   i.e., `'awk-script-goes-here'`
4. `NR` is an awk built-in variable that stands for record number (the number of the record currently being processed). By default, each line is a record.
5. By `f2[$2]=$1`  we are setting up an associative array `f2` with field2 (i.e., `$2`) as the index.
6. `$2 in f2` checks if the index is already present in the array.
7. The `if-else` and `printf` are self explanatory.
8. The `END` block in awk is executed only at the very end; i.e., after all the records have been processed.
9. `for(i in f2)` is a for loop construct used to parse the associative arrays in awk. It is the other way of saying, `for every index i in f2 do something`
10. Note that the above `for` loop may not print the array in an order. You may use the `sort` bash command to sort the array, though.
11. `next` goes to the next record without processing the commands that follow.
12. The `/pattern/` checks for a pattern in awk; the pattern `^$` checks for empty line.

**Reference**

If you wish to get expert in awk, [*Effective awk Programming*](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596000707.do) is a must read.

**Ugly one-liner**

```
awk -v FS="," '/^$/{next}{if(NR==1){f2[$2]=$1;next}else{if($2 in f2){f2[$2]=f2[$2]"-"$1;next}else{f2[$2]=$1;next}}}END{for(i in f2){printf "%s,%s\n",i,f2[i]}}' 299360
```

---

<sup>**Note:** Ideally, it's not a good idea to hard-code newlines in awk scripts, as in `printf "%s,%s\n",i,f2[i]`. You may replace it with `printf "%s,%s\n",i,f2[i];print` for extra portability.</sup>

Comment: Thanks I got the answer that i am expecting.It will be grateful if you explain the above command

Comment: @Rock . Thanks for accepting the answer, I have added comments -anything that follow `#` - after each line for better understanding

Comment: To the downvoter : What is the downvote for? Any suggestion to improve?

Comment: +1, but if you must use if-then-else constructs and `for` loops, please indent them to promote readability.  And spaces within the code lines are nice.  Also, be very *very **very*** careful about embedding single quotes in a string that’s delimited by single quotes. /  This doesn’t need to be so complicated; I have posted an alternative. /  Oddly, when I run your code, I get the same results, but in a different order (sorted by field2 value).  Can you explain the order that you are getting?  It’s not sorted by the data or the order of appearance. /  Also, what are you saying about using `\n`?

Comment: P.S. Congratulations on reaching 500 rep.

Comment: @G-Man A newline might be \n or \r\n depending on the system, so hardcoding a newline by using `either \n or \r\n` makes the solution less portable, A `print` on the other hand will handle it correctly.

Comment: @G-Man : Regarding the comments I've added to the script, I have appended it after posting the solution, so forgot about the single quotes.. Good catch and thankyou. Regarding the `for(i in f2)` no order is guaranteed as per [\[ awk documentation \]](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Arrays). Look for the line `The output does not come out in any useful order`.

Comment: I see. Alternatively, you could use the more compact `printf "%s,%s%s", i, f2[i], ORS` (although it is more cryptic).

Answer (score 6):

With GNU [datamash](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/manual/datamash.html):

```
datamash -t, -s -g 2 collapse 1 <data.txt | sed 's/,/-/2g'
```

Result:

```
254333,ysezaratlycpuggl-gqjp2rsjmk1a2v9c-twdzyi2ddbnrfknd-tpqorqbyrg1nmm7s
254341,gcmj7krrx5x6nf8r
254343,pw1jc5ssyt6hx618-pht92h4adr3mrbz3-alnac47rt8d4ege3
254344,hguvgstqxu3gowfg
```

Comment: beat me to it !

Answer (score 3):

In `perl`:

```perl
#! /usr/bin/perl

use strict;
my %mergecol = ();

while(<>) {
  s/#.*//;            # strip comments
  next if (m/^\s*$/); # skip empty lines
  chomp;
  my ($val,$key) = split ',';
  push @{ $mergecol{$key} }, $val;
};

foreach my $k (keys %mergecol) { 
  printf "%s,%s\n", $k, join('-', @{ $mergecol{$k} } );
}
```

The `while` loop reads the input and creates a Hash-of-Arrays (HoA) structure - an associative array where each element is an array (aka "list").  The keys to the hash are the second field, while the elements of each list are the first fields of lines with the same second field.

At the end of the script, the HoA is printed out one line per record, with the key name, a comma, and then the elements joined with a `-`.

run as:

```
$ ./rock.pl rock.txt
254341,gcmj7krrx5x6nf8r
254333,ysezaratlycpuggl-gqjp2rsjmk1a2v9c-twdzyi2ddbnrfknd-tpqorqbyrg1nmm7s
254344,hguvgstqxu3gowfg
254343,pw1jc5ssyt6hx618-pht92h4adr3mrbz3-alnac47rt8d4ege3
```

Or shortened and embedded in a shell command or script as a "one-liner":

```sh
$ perl -n -e '
    s/#.*//;
    next if (m/^\s*$/);
    chomp; ($v,$k)=split ","; push @{ $mc{$k} }, $v;
    END {
     foreach $k (keys %mc) { printf "%s,%s\n", $k, join("-",@{$mc{$k}}) }
    }' rock.txt
```

Or

```
$ perl -e 'while(<>) {s/#.*//;next if (m/^\s*$/);chomp;($v,$k)=split ",";push @{$mc{$k}}, $v};
    foreach $k (keys %mc) {printf "%s,%s\n",$k,join("-",@{$mc{$k}})}' rock.txt
```

Note that a hash or associative array is **inherently unordered**, if you want sorted output, either pipe into `sort` or use `(sort keys %f)` on the `foreach my $k` lines above.

Answer (score 2):

Building on [sjsam’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/299360/80216/merge-a-column-based-on-2nd-column#299361), but simpler:

```
awk -v FS="," '
    {
            f2[$2] = f2[$2] "-" $1   # append "-" and $1 to the current value
    }
    END {   # This code will be processed at the end
            for (i in f2) {  # for all the indexes i in f2
                             # (i.e., each unique value from column 2)
                             # print one line in the desired format
                printf "%s,%s\n", i, gensub("-", "", 1, f2[i])
            }
    }
'
```

This simple-mindedly builds strings that look like this:

```
   -       pw1jc5ssyt6hx618      -       pht92h4adr3mrbz3      -       alnac47rt8d4ege3
(hyphen)       (value)        (hyphen)       (value)        (hyphen)       (value)
```

(but without the spaces; they’re just for illumination). 
Then, when it comes time to print the data, it removes the first **`-`**
using the general substitution function, `gensub()`.  Unfortunately,
this isn’t supported in [the POSIX specification for `awk`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html);
it requires GNU Awk. 
Alternatively, you could change `gensub("-", "", 1, f2[i])`
to `substr(f2[i], 2)` and get the substring of `f2[i]`
from the second character to the end
(i.e., all but the first character, which is **`-`**),
in a POSIX-compliant way.

This will (attempt to) process every line in the input. 
If there are some lines in the input that should be ignored
(e.g., blank lines), you could change the first part to

```
    /./ {
            f2[$2] = f2[$2] "-" $1   # …
    }
```

or

```
    NF==2 {
            f2[$2] = f2[$2] "-" $1   # …
    }
```

---

When I run sjsam’s answer or my own, I get

```
254333,ysezaratlycpuggl-gqjp2rsjmk1a2v9c-twdzyi2ddbnrfknd-tpqorqbyrg1nmm7s
254341,gcmj7krrx5x6nf8r
254343,pw1jc5ssyt6hx618-pht92h4adr3mrbz3-alnac47rt8d4ege3
254344,hguvgstqxu3gowfg
```

i.e., sorted by the value of the column 2 key. 
You show the desired output
in order of first appearance of the column 2 key in the input. 
If that’s important to you, try:

```
awk -v FS="," '
    {
            if (! ($2 in f2)) appearance[++x] = $2
            f2[$2] = f2[$2] "-" $1   # append "-" and $1 to the current value
    }
    END {   # This code will be processed at the end
            for (ix in appearance) {
                             # for all the indexes i in f2
                             # (i.e., each unique value from column 2)
                             # print one line in the desired format
                i = appearance[ix]
                printf "%s,%s\n", i, gensub("-", "", 1, f2[i])
            }
    }
'
```

which uses the `appearance` array to keep track of the order of appearance.

Comment: Nice, but you might need a small note that this will work only on `gnu-awk` which is fine as per the problem. Also this won't remove the blank lines in the input( though the op has mentioned nothing about it). Otherwise ++ :)

Comment: Yeah, I keep forgetting what GNU Awk features are extensions. Regarding blank lines, (1) I did mention the fact that I wasn’t handling them specially, and how the script could be adjusted to do that, and (2) the OP is a newbie.  SE newbies often type blank lines in data just to get hard returns, because they don’t understand how to do code / preformatted blocks.  That seems to be what happened here.

Answer (score 1):

With two-dimensional arrays found in GNU `awk`

```
awk -F, '{
  a[$2][$1]
  }
  END{
    for (i in a) {
      c=0; printf "%s,", i; 
        for (j in a[i]) {
          ++c; printf "%s%s", j, length(a[i]) == c? "\n": "-"
          }
     }
   }' file
```

Comment: Hardcoding a newline will makes the script less portable, though in this case it nbd